# How to split an image folder based on file names found in a data frame?

Tags: python, image

I have a df called "data" from a .csv file that contains metadata for thousands of images. I filtered that dataframe  based on a specific value, and then down to one column called image_id where each row represents a file name. I renamed this new, one column dataframe to "image_names".

I have a separate folder containing thousands of images. I'd like to split this image folder into 2: one of the folders contains the files whose image_ids are found in my image_names df, and the second folder contains the rest.

I feel like this is so simple but I am so stuck on how to do this. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
import os.path
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

OldFolder= Path("R:\\This Is\\The Old\\Path")
NewFolder= Path("R:\\This Is\\The New\\Path")

for file_name in data.image_names:
    shutil.move(OldFolder / file_name, NewFolder / file_name)
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please upvote and  mark it as accepted to make it easier for others to find the answer.